# squid TAG_NONE/503 0 CONNECT when high load

Tags: networking, server, proxy, squid

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with a Squid on cloud server.
Squid is used for my Android application to access few web sites.
In general everything worked fine until 3 days ago during the highest load period (9 PM - 11 PM), when I have ~20 000 active users. During this time I am getting a lot of Squid logs like this:

```
2017.09.13/19:08:46      0 79.143.34.171 TAG_NONE/503 0 CONNECT login.vk.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
```

I'm investigating already for 2 days, and what I've tried so far is disable caching, disable IPv6, using `via off` and `forwarded_for off`, using `http_port 0.0.0.0:8080` to force IP v4, setting `tcp_outgoing_address <server_ip_address>`, and some more things, that I currently can't remember.

So firstly I don't understand that 503 code: is that the response from the web site `login.vk.com`, right? Does it mean that that site (server) is overloaded by requests, or just exceeds the requests per second from my server's IP?

How can I fix this, or at least improve the situation? Maybe I should somehow limit max simultaneous connections to my Squid?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with a web page of a bank, the log is:

```
TAG_NONE / 503 0 CONNECT enlinea.bt.gob.ve:443 - HIER_NONE / - -
```

What I did was place:

```
pinger_enable off
half_closed_clients off
quick_abort_min 0 KB
quick_abort_max 0 KB
quick_abort_pct 95
```

And change:

```
client_persistent_connections on
server_persistent_connections on
```

By:

```
client_persistent_connections off
server_persistent_connections off
```

It immediately began to work after changing those settings.

Comment: thanks, definitely worth a try and upvote. But maibe you could also explain what each options means?

Comment: For those who find it but dont understand : look up these directives at http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config.